# What Type to use for Generic IList Method

Tags: c#, generics, covariant

I have tried to write a method that converts any IList of things into a comma-separated list of those things as a string. It looks like this:

```
public static string ToStringList<T>(this T source) where T : IList<object>
{
    string list_string = "[EMPTY]";
    try
    {
        if (source != null && source.Count() > 0)
        {
            list_string = "";
            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                //ToString unnecessarily written here to highlight the usage
                list_string += $", {item.ToString()}";
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        list_string = "[ERROR - could not list values]";
    }
    list_string = list_string.StartsWith(", ") ? list_string.Substring(2) : list_string;
    return list_string;
}
```

I would like to use this method on an Observable collection of Sites:

```
public class Site
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

however, when I try to run the following code, I get a conversion error:

```
public ObservableCollection<Site> SelectedSites {get;set;}
//[some skipped code that inserts values into the ObservableCollection]

//Error: Cannot convert from Site to object
var sites = SelectedSites.ToStringList();
```

I understand why I get the conversion error - there is no way for the code to know how to convert the `Site` into an `object`. However, given that `ToString()` exists on everything, is there a way that I can alter the method `ToStringList()` such that it can accept an IList of any type?

I have read some articles and pages about IList (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559070/why-generic-ilist-does-not-inherit-non-generic-ilist) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075866/c-sharp-generic-list-of-generic-list-of-multiple-types)), but honestly they have as much confused as enlightened - is that because what I ask is impossible or so long winded as to be impractical (in which case I can find another way)?

I am using .NET Framework 4.8.

Comment: Does that fit? `public static string ToStringList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)`

Comment: You generic method returns `string` instead of `List<string>`. Olivier Rogier mentioned about that already. There's another issue. Think of it!

Comment: @OlivierRogier if only you had put this as an answer, I could have given you credit for a correct answer; this is the solution I have eventually implemented as per Sweeper's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your extension method isn't available on an `ObservableCollection<Site>`, because an `IList<Site>` isn't related to `IList<object>` at all (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/convert-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass) for why).

You can instead use `IList<T>` as the parameter type:

```
public static string ToStringList<T>(this IList<T> source)
```

Now this will be available on `ObservableCollection<Site>`, because it implements `IList<Site>`, and the compiler can infer that `T` is `Site`.

Since you are not using any of the specific things that `IList<T>` provides, you can also define this method for the more general `IEnumerable<T>`. However, calling `Count()` on a general `IEnumerable` could be an O(n) operation. You might want to use `Any()` to check if there is any elements instead.

```
public static string ToStringList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
```

Also note that you seem to be reinventing `string.Join` a little bit:

```
public static string ToStringList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    try
    {
        const string empty = "[EMPTY]";
        if (source != null)
        {
            return string.Join(", ", source.Select(x => x.ToString()).DefaultIfEmpty(empty));
        }
        else
        {
            return empty;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return "[ERROR - could not list values]";
    }
}
```

Comment: I was getting too bound up in the `where T : ...` part and became blind to the fact that I could set more in the parameter itself! Also, good point about string.Join - this works perfectly. What a wasted morning - thank you for ending the waste!

Comment: Since the example uses `.Count()`, using `IReadOnlyCollection` instead of `IEnumerable` might be appropriate, or add a `.DefaultIfEmpty("[EMPTY]")` after the `.Select`.

Comment: @JonasH You mean `Count()` might consume the entire enumerable? That's a good point! How about using `Any()` instead?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, .Count() will cause multiple enumerations. `.Any()` is better, since it will will stop after the first item, but can still be a problem the enumeration is a complex (and slow) query that does not result in any items. I would still recommend `.DefaultifEmpty` since that avoids the issue altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
public static string ToStringList<T>(this T source) where T : IList<object>
```

To

```
public static string ToStringList<T>(this IList<T> source) where T : class
```

Comment: while I cannot mark more than one answer as the accepted answer, this also works, so could have been accepted. I went with @Sweeper because it is a more concise way to write the change.